# FreeNAS and Ubuntu install on same machine

Tags: cloud, nas

I wanted to know if anyone has installed FreeNAS and Ubuntu on the same machine by partitioning the Hard Drive?

What I'm looking to do is have a NAS and wanted to experiment running [OwnCloud](http://owncloud.org). Or and I going about this all wrong.

I have a couple of HDTV (Boxee) Machines and wanted to move to a centralized Media location (FreeNAS), but also wanted to access some stuff from the web as well for my Mobile devices and maybe sharing some family movies/photos with relatives (OwnCloud).

Other ideas are welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no reason you can not dual boot. Another option might be to run FreeNAS in Ubuntu with Virtualization, you would then not need to reboot just to try FreeNAS

Here is a tutorial on running FreeNAS in virtualbox (hope it helps)

http://samkear.com/how-to-guides/installing-freenas-virtualbox

If you prefer, here is a tutorial on dual booting Ubuntu and FreeBSD, should work with FreeNAS

http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-doc/2009-November/016465.html

Comment: no way to run the together? side by side without virtual box? or if virtual box what would be the latency?

Comment: If you want to run them both at the same time you need some kind of virtualization. There are alternates to VirtualBox - KVM, VMWare are both popular.

Comment: Funny to resurrect this topic, but I'd like to add that FreeNAS now runs OwnCloud as a plugin, so there shouldn't be any real reason why the machine would need to run Ubuntu server (not for running OwnCloud, anyway).